# How to implement comet on php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, comet

I would like to develop a ticketing system,if any new tickets come that should appear top of the old list like a `gmail`(new mails on top),so i referred some articles which says that `ajax` is not good and go through `COMET`, So please suggest some example for implement comet on **php**. Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for your replay amadan, is there any choice to make my need possible?

Comment: The link I posted is a possibility, but the important thing is that you can't do Comet using Apache, which is how most PHP webpages are deployed. Comet can't work through Apache, or Nginx, they need to be on a standalone server because of the way they work (using a server socket). If that does not work (I have not tested it), using socket.io with JavaScript is probably the best nicest way to do it.

Comment: thanks amadan pretty cool